При запуске кода Visual Studio Code выдает ошибку, якобы файл не найден в директории, помогите исправить
# инициализируем класс YOLO
WORK_DIR='C:\Users\valer\Downloads\Sozdanie_pervogo_bota_s_OD\Sozdanie_pervogo_bota_s_OD'
# os.makedirs(WORK_DIR, exist_ok=True)
yolov5 = TerraYoloV5(work_dir=WORK_DIR)

Выдает вот такую ошибку:

PS C:\Users\valer\Downloads\Sozdanie_pervogo_bota_s_OD> python .\Lesson.py
C:\Users\valer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\valer\Downloads\Sozdanie_pervogo_bota_s_OD\Lesson.py': 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory

Помогите исправить.

А ваш скрипт действительно лежит по этому пути: C:\Users\valer\Downloads\Sozdanie_pervogo_bota_s_OD\Lesson.py?

да, лежит по этому пути. В проводнике путь указан C:\Поьзователи\valer\Загрузки\Sozdanie_pervogo_bota_s_OD\Lesson.py    Когда правой кнопкой копирую путь он копируется в таком виде C:\Users\valer\Downloads\Sozdanie_pervogo_bota_s_OD\Lesson.py  Может из-за этого ошибка ?

Да вроде должно и так и так работать. Хотя есть мнение, что питон не любит локализованные пути и лучше без них чтобы файлы лежали

спасибо, переименовала файлы, код запустился, но выдал новую ошибку "Invalid file http url specified: wrong port number specified in the url" Помогите исправить.

Только полный стек-трейс ошибки, так не угадать

переместила файлы, все заработало)
